# Press OK on pop-up alert window via VBA

Tags: excel, vba, automation

Having an issue, I have written a Macro ,that refreshes every 2 min, to upload data from a webpage and the last step of my Macro is using "Text to column" function so that it will be splitted into columns nicely.

The problem appears here everytime it gets to executes this "Text to column" it asks if I want to overwrite the columns(and I DO), but I need to press manually OK.

Is there any way to make VBA press this OK button in the alert?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `DoCmd.SendKeys` BEFORE the instruction that generates the  dialog.

Comment: @user2087878: it would be better to add that code as an update to your question. Since you are new, don't forget to mark it as code (or ident it by 4 char) to make it more readable.

Answer (score 3):

Just add `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` prior to the call, and set it back to `True` after.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa175241%28v=office.11%29.aspx

---

Update: I just ran a test and it does not prompt me by default. Can you post the code you're using? I simply did:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Columns("A:A")
    r.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("B1")
End Sub
```

[This link](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/592379-eliminate-text-to-columns-prompt.html) says the `DisplayAlerts` solution has worked in for others.

Comment: I tried, added but it still pups-up this alert and I still need to press OK in order to it go forward.

Comment: Saved my situation: Thank you!!! Works fine with Application.DisplayAlerts = False/True

Comment: There should be a large, clear check mark to the left of my answer(under the big "2"). Just click it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use mouse click function
Before it maximize window so x,y cordinates of ok buttons remain same
Use windows lib 32